# PHP file_exists returns false with existing files

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm having a little problem with my PHP-code. I want to create a site which has different directories. Every directories has a file named pass (not .txt or something) with the value of the directories password. So if the pass-file doesn't exist the group will not exist. But even if the group exists it still says the group doesn't exist and I can't fopen the file either, but I can locate to it. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$group = $_POST['group'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$filename = '/groups/' . $group . '/pass';
if(file_exists($filename)){
    $handle = fopen($filename) or die("can't open file");
    $hoi = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    if ($pass === $hoi){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    }
    else{
        echo 'Password is wrong!';
    }
}
else{
    echo 'Group does not exist!';
}
?>
```

All POST-data is correct btw. Thanks for your help!

Comment: try to give full path always.

Comment: `$filename = '/groups/' . $group . '/pass';` is an absolute file path, so you are essentially (assuming you use windows for this reference) seeing if `c:/groups/....` exists.

Comment: the path to the file should be absolute. Suggested way should be use:
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));  // define('ROOT', 'c:\\somedir');

then use $filename =  ROOT . '/groups/' . $group . '/pass';

Comment: _“Every directories has a file named pass (not .txt or something) with the value of the directories password”_ – that’s great news for everyone who knows how your system works and wants to hack into it – because now they can simply request `/groups/foobar/pass` via their browser … (unless you have specifically prevented HTTP access to those files in some way?)

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, I know, I am gonna do contrahacking later but first I want this to work, you see.

Comment: Use extension like .php or .html. without this you will not always get false result.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that file *pass* must have ending. **eg. .php or .html or something** File name `'/groups/' . $group . '/pass';` is wrong.

PHP function is named *file_exist()* and files must have endings!

If it is folder it has sometimes slash at the end. But it can be file. With `.htaccess` redirect, on index.html or index.php could be slash at the end of the file.